# what causes [corebluetooth] XPC connection invalid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins, core-bluetooth

So let me start of by saying I am new to Objective-C and pretty much all of my experience has been in very high-level languages like javascript and ruby so learning it has been tough and I know there are a lot of concepts I don't have a good grasp on.

I am currently building a cordova plugin to be able to integrate the [MagTek eDynamo reader](https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d998200110.pdf) into cordova IOS apps. My plugin is based largely off of [this](https://github.com/eGood/CardReaderPlugin) plugin and I have been using the existing code along with the [Magtek SDK Documentation](https://www.magtek.com/content/documentationfiles/d99875568.pdf)/(the sample code in the SDK) to work my way through updating the plugin.

Now to my problem: Every time I call the openDevice function I am getting the error in the title. [corebluetooth] XPC connection invalid. I have looked this up and have gotten pretty confused by other answers on stack overflow and some blogs I found discussing the error. From what I understand it is thrown when there are multiple instances of CBCentralManager, or when it is referenced as a local variable instead of a strong reference to the class. To be honest I think this is where my lack of experience with objective-c and mid/lower level languages in general is really hurting me because I don't really understand these answers and from what I thought the SDK files and functions were taking care of the interaction with core bluetooth so I'm not really sure what I am doing to cause problems with core bluetooth at all.

I have been stuck on this for over a week now and I really don't know what to try next.

Thank you in advance for any insight and I am willing to provide any more code or logs that might be helpful although all of the code for the plugin is in [this Github repo.](https://github.com/kevinjung2/CardReaderPlugin/tree/ios-branch)

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/kevinjung2/CardReaderPlugin/tree/ios-branch there is not a single reference to "XPC connection invalid".

In foundation there is a XPC connection invalid error from Cocoa framework.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/cocoaerror/2293178-xpcconnectioninvalid/

In the lack of more information I'm guessing that your driver are not updated to what the Cocoa framework are expecting for open a connection.

MAYBE, and this is just a guess... Apple changed something in their API that needs to be updated in the driver.

On the repository provided there is a https://github.com/eGood/CardReaderPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/libMTSCRA.a file that is not open for change and further investigation with easy. Pehaps the needed-to-update-function that provides metadata to open a connection to bluetooth are created there. And, in this case, there is nothing to do unless ask for the Magtek to update their driver.

EDIT: Have you tried what the manufacturer said in section 3.3.2... they have a test app. Try to connect with theirs... if it works, then you know is something wrong in your app, but if theirs didn't work either. Is most likely my hypothesis above.